# R leaflet: adding an information popup using easyButton

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

I am building a leaflet map within R Studio and I want to place an information icon on the top-left of the map as an easyButton which allows users to click and popup some text information with some hyperlinks. The example text I would like to show is something like this:

**Title of paragraph 1**
Information about this particular feature.

**Title of paragraph 2**
Information about a different feature. Here is a [link](https://tomjenkins.netlify.app/) to more info.

Below is a reproducible example of what I have got so far. At present, I have an 'alert' but a simple popup would be preferred, though I have limited knowledge of JavaScript so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(leaflet)

leaf = leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addEasyButton(easyButton(
    icon = htmltools::span(class = "star", htmltools::HTML("&starf;")),
    onClick = JS("function(btn, map){ map.setZoom(1);}")))

leaf %>% addEasyButton(easyButton(
  icon = "fa-info-circle", title = "Map Information",
  onClick = JS("function(btn, map){ alert('Note: this feature is still in development') }")))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just added a similar feature to my map by using the hints in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46590754) answer. The solution uses a [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) as an overlay and is easily configurable via the CSS tags in the info.box HTML.

Instead of adding `htmlDependency` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35775262), which did not work for me with R leaflet, just use the built-in function `addBootstrapDependency()`. After creating the leaflet map, which is "just" a htmlwidget, add the defined infobox-HTML to the object with `htmlwidgets::appendContent(info.box)`.

A solution using the info you provided:

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

# Define HTML for the infobox
info.box <- HTML(paste0(
  HTML(
    '<div class="modal fade" id="infobox" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><!-- Modal content--><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>'
  ),

  # Header / Title
  HTML("Note: This feature is still in development"),
  HTML(
    '</div><div class="modal-body">'
  ),

  # Body
  HTML('<h4>Title of paragraph 1</h4>
<p>Information about this particular feature.</p>
<hr>
<h4>Title of paragraph 2</h4>
<p>Information about a different feature. Here is a <a href="https://tomjenkins.netlify.app/">link</a> to more info.</p>'),

  # Closing divs
  HTML('</div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div></div>')
))

# Define the map
leaf <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addBootstrapDependency() %>% # Add Bootstrap to be able to use a modal
  addEasyButton(easyButton(
    icon = htmltools::span(class = "star", htmltools::HTML("&starf;")),
    onClick = JS("function(btn, map){ map.setZoom(1);}")
  )) %>%
  addEasyButton(easyButton(
    icon = "fa-info-circle", title = "Map Information",
    onClick = JS("function(btn, map){ $('#infobox').modal('show'); }")
  )) %>% # Trigger the infobox
  htmlwidgets::appendContent(info.box)

leaf
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps you! Would love to see something similar integrated in the `leaflet` package.